# Create a tiff with only images and no text from a postscript file with ghostscript

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, postscript

Is it possible to create a tiff file from a postscript-file (created from a pdf-document with readable text and images) into a tiff file without the text and only the images?

[There is a way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6437564/create-a-tiff-with-only-text-and-no-images-from-a-postscript-file-with-ghostscri/) to create a tiff with no images, but I don't know how to use that way for my task. I need it to generate two images from a postscript-file - [the first one](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/16751380/1.jpg) with the images only and the [second one](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/16751380/1.png) with the text only.

Since the text is drawn over the top of the image, simple clipping won't do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hack the text out by redefining the `show` operators to no-ops. Insert this after the `%%Page` comment line (where the page code really starts).

```
/show{pop}def
/ashow{3{pop}repeat}def
/widthshow{4{pop}repeat}def
/awidthshow{6{pop}repeat}def
/kshow{2{pop}repeat}def

/xshow{2{pop}repeat}def
/xyshow{2{pop}repeat}def
/yshow{2{pop}repeat}def
/glyphshow{pop}def
/cshow{2{pop}repeat}def
```

This will suppress all text-drawing operators. *Edit: Now includes level 2 and 3 operators.*

If you're trying to selectively suppress different kinds of elements, you may want to redefine only some of these operators. You can add `%` at the beginning of a line to *comment-out* a line of the code, keeping the full list intact (for future uses).

Comment: Thank you for your help! Unfortunately it doesn't work.
[Here is](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/16751380/1.ps) the postscript-file.

Comment: I've edited to add a few more. Also, you should add more detail to the question to get it reopened.

Comment: It really does work! Thank you very much!
And wich operators should I redefine to hide boxes, lines and vector graphic?

Comment: There are lots of operators that can be used for line drawing. Check the [PLRM](http://www.adobe.com/products/postscript/pdfs/PLRM.pdf) 8.1 Operator Summary, Painting Operators. At some point you're better off clipping out the elements you want, suppressing everything else.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to selectively suppress elements from a ps file is to use the powerful clipping mechanism.

```
144 288 72 72 rectclip % clip to a 1"x1" square 2" from the left, 4" from the bottom
```

Clip works with an arbitrary path. So you can even string together points in a connect-the-dots fashion to get the effect of a lasso-clip. Probably easiest if you print the image out and trace a grid to easily plot points for the trajectory.

```
100 100 moveto
200 200 lineto
300 100 lineto
500 500 lineto
200 700 lineto
closepath clip  % clip to a non-rectangular convex polygon
```

Clipping will suppress all drawing operations that fall outside of the clippath while the clipping path is in effect.