# Small pdf files results with huge BufferdImage

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract, pdfbox, bufferedimage

I'm trying to perform OCR on pdfs.
There are 2 steps in the code:

1. Convert pdf to tiff files
2. Convert tiff to text

I used ghost4j for the first step, and then tess4j for the second one.
all worked great, until I started to do run it multi-threaded, and then strange exceptions occurred.
I read here: https://sourceforge.net/p/tess4j/discussion/1202293/thread/44cc65c5/
that ghost4j is not suitable for multi-threaded, so I changed the first step to work with PDFBox.

So now my code looks like:

```
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(this.bytes);
PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(doc);
BufferedImage bufferedImage = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(0, 300);
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "tiff", os);
os.flush();
os.close();
bufferedImage.flush();
```

I'm trying to run this code with a 800 kb pdf file, and when checking the memory after the

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(0, 300);
```

it raise to more than 500 MB!! if i'm saving this BufferedImage to disk the output is 1 MB size...so when trying to run this code with 8 threads, I'm getting the java heap size exception also...

What am I missing here? why a 1 MB file results in a 500 MB image file? I tried to play with the DPI and reduce the quality but the file is still very big...
Is there any other library that can render pdf to tiff, and that I could execute 10 threads without memory issues?

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Download the Linkedin CEO resume file from here - https://gofile.io/?c=TtA7XQ
2. I than used this code:

   ```
   private static void test() throws IOException {
       printUsedMemory("App started...");
       File file = new File("linkedinceoresume.pdf");
       try (PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(file)) {
           PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(doc);
           printUsedMemory("Before");
           for (int page = 0; page < 1; ++page) {
               BufferedImage bufferedImage = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(page, 76, ImageType.GRAY);
               ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
               ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "tiff", os);
               os.flush();
               os.close();
               bufferedImage.flush();
           }
       } finally {
           printUsedMemory("BufferedImage");
       }
   }

   private static void printUsedMemory(String text) {
       long freeMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
       long mb = freeMemory / 1000000;
       System.out.println(text + "....Used memory: " + mb + " MB");
   }
   ```

and the output is:

> App started.......Used memory: 42 MB
>
> Before....Used memory: 107 MB
>
> BufferedImage....Used memory: 171 MB

In this example it's not 500 MB, but a pdf of 70 kb, when I try to render only one page, the memory increase in about 70 MB...it's not proportional...

Comment: Please share the PDF file. Maybe if has a huge image dimension output size?

Comment: Can you check the dimensions of your `BufferedImage` after rendering?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't share the file.
When using the DPI 300, the dimensions are 3300 X 2550. changing to DPI 76 the dimensions are 836 X 646...memory size is almost the same
Tested with 4-5 different pdf files, all results with this huge size...

Comment: It is propably not because of the coversion then. Maybe you have a memory leak elsewhere?

Comment: Note that high memory consumption doesn't necessarily indicate a memory leak. Perhaps the page contains a bitmap object that needs a lot of memory to decode? Does PDFBox subsample images when rendering at smaller sizes? If not, rendering at a small size may not help...

Comment: Pdfbox does not subsample by default but it can be enabled in PDFRenderer.

Comment: I edited the main post with some info how to reproduce

Comment: Have you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6437564/create-a-tiff-with-only-text-and-no-images-from-a-postscript-file-with-ghostscri ?

Comment: @TobiasOtto not sure how is that pose can help...

Comment: @TilmanHausherr What are we suppose to do when we have a PDF that includes a picture with big resolution? For testing purpose, I created a small pdf (1 Mo) with only one page that includes an image with a huge resolution, it consumed more than 4 Go to convert it into an image. Is there something we can do to avoid that?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto activate subsampling in PDFRenderer. But subsampling is probably not a good idea for OCR.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I confirm that it works well in my case, thank you for the tip

Answer (score 0):

A dimension 3300 X 2550 of one byte per pixel would deliver around 70_000_000 bytes.
With 150 dpi one would have 22 inch by 17 inch, way too huge.

So scale the picture down to approx. 17 MB memory:

```
    float scale = 0.5f;
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = pdfRenderer.renderImage(page, scale, ImageType.BINARY);
```

Save it as `png` rather than `tiff` to see whether that makes a difference.

Comment: The OP wants to do OCR, so 300dpi is a good choice. But you're right on the image type, I have made the same suggestion in PDFBOX-4739. (It also came out that the images are saved uncompressed)

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I partly do OCR with 150 dpi successfully but indeed 300 dpi is the norm. Using a ByteArrayOutputStream as above might be costly too,

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved in the discussion in [PDFBOX-4739](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4739):

- use `ImageIOUtils.writeImage()` instead of `ImageIO.write()` (you will need the tools subproject), because ImageIO doesn't compress TIFF files. ImageIOUtils tries to use LZW or CCITT, depending on the source image.
- don't save the image at all: there is a `doOCR()` method that takes a BufferedImage as parameter, so no need to save at all.